# Copy data from C1FlexGrid to C1FlexGrid

Tags: vb.net, componentone

I'm using a C1FlexGrid, which version I'm not entirely sure. I am trying to copy rows that are selected in FlexGridA to FlexGridB, and so far I'm unable to locate anything online to help, and all of the functionality that I've tried to use so far (such as add) does not work.

How can I accomplish this?

I *HAVE* to use C1FlexGrids, so if the answer is for a regular MSFlexGrid it won't work. I've already tried using some solutions for those and they don't work either.

EDIT:

I now have information copying between tables, but it's copying the entirety of what the table has after it's filtered, not just the selected rows.

There are two flexgrids. On form1 is fgResults, on form2 is fgDelete. I want to copy the selected rows from fgResults to fgDelete so that a user can see what they've selected to delete from the database before just blindly clicking and deleting something they don't want to.

Here is what I have to copy the data:

```
            AddFilterRow(MultiDelete.fgDelete)
            Dim MS As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
            fgResults.WriteXml(MS)
            MS.Position = 0
            MultiDelete.fgDelete.ReadXml(MS)
```

The issue is, again, it's adding EVERYTHING that was filtered, not just the selected rows.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we just may be able to help you.

Comment: I added the code I currently have that is at least copying information between the grids. It's not the correct information, but it's a start.

Comment: There can be a very simple solution where you can save the grid A with appropriate FileFlag.SelectedRowsOnly in a temporary file and later load the same file in the grid B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several hours of digging, I found a workaround as there doesn't appear to be a direct way to copy one row from a C1FlexGrid to another.

```
            Dim DT As New DataTable

            For c = fgResults.Cols.Fixed To fgResults.Cols.Count - 1
                DT.Columns.Add(fgResults.Cols(c).Name, fgResults.Cols(c).DataType)
            Next

            For r = fgResults.Rows.Fixed To fgResults.Rows.Count - 1
                If fgResults.Rows(r).Selected Then
                    Dim row As DataRow = DT.NewRow()
                    For c = fgResults.Cols.Fixed To fgResults.Cols.Count - 1
                        If fgResults(r, c) Is Nothing Then
                            If fgResults.Cols(c).DataType.FullName = "System.DateTime" Then
                                row.Item(c - fgResults.Cols.Fixed) = Date.MinValue
                            ElseIf fgResults.Cols(c).DataType.FullName = "System.Double" Then
                                row.Item(c - fgResults.Cols.Fixed) = 0
                            Else
                                row.Item(c - fgResults.Cols.Fixed) = ""
                            End If

                        Else
                            row.Item(c - fgResults.Cols.Fixed) = fgResults(r, c)
                        End If
                    Next
                    DT.Rows.Add(row)
                End If
            Next
```

What I'm doing here is creating a new datatable, adding all rows to it that are selected, and then I fill the second grid with the created datatable. If anyone has a more direct way of doing this I am all ears, but this works for now for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

i have the code to copy c1 flex grid cells to excel format

```
Dim fCol as integer
Dim fRow as integer
 Private Sub Flex_EnterCell(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Flex.EnterCell

        fRow = Flex.RowSel
        fCol = Flex.ColSel
    End Sub


Private Sub Copy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Copy.Click
        Dim lRow As Integer, nRow As Integer
        Dim lCol As Integer, nCol As Integer
        Dim nText As String

        lRow = Flex.RowSel
        lCol = Flex.ColSel
        For nRow = fRow To lRow
            For nCol = fCol To lCol
                nText = nText & IIf(IsDBNull(Flex.Item(nRow, nCol)), Convert.ToChar(Keys.Tab), Flex.Item(nRow, nCol)) & Convert.ToChar(Keys.Tab)
            Next
            nText = nText & vbCrLf
        Next
        Clipboard.SetText(nText)

    End Sub
```